# overlay one video on top of anotherusing ffmpeg with time delay on overaly video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have tried the below command but the output file length is coming same as overlay video

```
ffmpeg -i bg.webm -i ol.webm -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1/TB[delayedGif];[0:v][delayedGif]overlay=enable='between(t,1,3)'[out]" -map [out] completesetpts.webm
```

I have also tried the below command but it cuts the overlay video upto between start duration

```
ffmpeg -i background.webm -vf "movie=overlay.webm, scale=250: -1 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay =10:10:enable='between(t, 05, 13)' [out]" output.webm
```

Main Video 5mins
Overlay 2min should start from 1min
The output video of 5mins overlay should start from 1min to 3min

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.webm -ss 60 -i ol.webm -filter_complex \
    "[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1/TB[delayedGif];\
     [0:v][delayedGif]overlay=enable='between(t,1,3)':shortest=1[out]" \
  -map [out] completesetpts.webm
```

- `-ss 60` start to read `ol.webm` from 60-second mark
- `overlay=...:shortest=1` kills the filter's output whenever one of its input ends
- Some of the numbers (`1` and `3`) in your filtergraph look suspicious. If you meant them to be in minutes, make sure to multiply them by 60 as FFmpeg expects seconds.